# How would you do a comment system with revision?

Tags: php, database, design-patterns, database-design, doctrine-orm

I need to implement a comment system with revision.

I'm using Doctrine2.

I need all to store all the comments when they are edited, but only display the last for the moment, however I need to be able to show all the old comments and always show the count of comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Versionable in the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

Basically you make your Entity implement `Versionable` and add a version field. It comes bundled with a VersionManager to allow you to rollback to specific versions.

The version field on the Entity will indicate the number of revisions.

Comment: pretty interesting, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... I'll let you fill in the blanks:

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class Comment
{

    private $name;

    private $email;

    private $website;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="CommentVersion") */
    private $versions;

    public function __construct($name, $website, $email, $comment)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->website = $website;
        $this->setComment($comment);
    }

    public function setComment($text)
    {
        $this->versions->add(new CommentVersion($text));
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        $latestVersion = false;
        foreach($this->versions as $version){
            if(!$latestVersion){
                $latestVersion = $version;
                continue;
            }

            if($version->getCreatedAt() > $latestVersion->getCreatedAt()){
                $latestVersion = $version;
            }
        }

        return $latestVersion->getComment();
    }

    public function getRevisionHistory()
    {
        return $this->comments->toArray();
    }

}

/** @Entity */
class CommentVersion
{

    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $comment;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $createdAt;

    public function __construct($comment)
    {
        $this->comment   = $comment;
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

}
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```
<?php

$comment = new Comment("Cobby", "http://cobbweb.me", "my@email.com", "Some comment text");
$em->persist($comment);
$em->flush();

$comment->getComment(); // Some comment text

$comment->setComment("Revision 2");
$dm->flush();

$comment->getComment(); // Revision 2

$comment->getRevisionHistory();
// CommentVersion(0): "Some comment text"
// CommentVersion(1): "Revision 2"
```

I haven't tested this, but you get the idea...